# jQuery functionality lost in all items except the first, when using a loop

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, loops, modal-dialog

In the following page,  begins an element that enables user to crop and save an image. It only works for the first item in the loop however, for all the sql rows that follow, clicking the image doesn't open up the modal-dialog box.

I don't have any overlapping tags, I've checked thoroughly. I've moved around the js script tags and don't get any change either. Is there a common cause for this? where would be the first place to troubleshoot? Would using a different type of loop in PHP be preferable?

```
        <?php 
    ob_start();
    session_start();
    require_once ('verify.php'); 
    ?>
    <head>
    <title>Edit Listings</title>
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../css/cropper.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../css/crop-avatar.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="container">
      <div id="head">
        <ul id="menu">
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div id="area"></div>
      <div id="main_listings">
        <h1 align="left">Edit listings page</h1>
        <?php
    include ("../dbcon2.php");
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    $sql="SELECT * FROM listings ORDER BY date_added DESC";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
        ?>
        <?php while ($data=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)):
                $id = $data['id'];
                $id = $data['title'];
                $listing_img = $data['listing_img'];
        ?>
        <div id="edit_listing">
          <div id="edit_left">
            <div class="container" id="crop-avatar">
              <div class="avatar-view" title="Change the avatar"> <img src="<?php echo $listing_img; ?>" alt="<?php echo $title; ?>"> </div>
              <div class="modal fade" id="avatar-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="avatar-modal-label" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                  <div class="modal-content">
                    <form class="avatar-form" method="post" action="edit-avatar.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                      <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="avatar-modal-label">Listing Main Image</h4>
                      </div>
                      <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="avatar-body">
                          <div class="avatar-upload">
                            <input class="avatar-src" name="avatar_src" type="hidden">
                            <input class="avatar-data" name="avatar_data" type="hidden">
                            <input name="avatar_id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
                            <label for="avatarInput">Local upload</label>
                            <input class="avatar-input" id="avatarInput" name="avatar_file" type="file">
                          </div>
                          <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-9">
                              <div class="avatar-wrapper"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-3">
                              <div class="avatar-preview preview-lg"></div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary avatar-save" type="submit">Save</button>
                      </div>
                    </form>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="loading" tabindex="-1" role="img" aria-label="Loading"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div id="edit_right">
            <form name="edit_date" action="edit_list.php" method="post" id="edit_list_data">
              <input name="title" type="text" id="title" tabindex="1" value="<?php echo $title; ?>" size="60" maxlength="57"/>
              <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" />
              <input type="submit" formaction="edit_list.php" value="Submit" />
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
        <?php endwhile;$conn->close();?>
        <div class="spacer"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="../js/cropper.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="../js/crop-avatar.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html><?php // Flush the buffered output.
        ob_end_flush();
    ?>
```

js    js

```
 // Events
          EVENT_MOUSE_DOWN = "mousedown touchstart",
          EVENT_MOUSE_MOVE = "mousemove touchmove",
          EVENT_MOUSE_UP = "mouseup mouseleave touchend touchleave touchcancel",
          EVENT_WHEEL = "wheel mousewheel DOMMouseScroll",
          EVENT_RESIZE = "resize" + CROPPER_NAMESPACE, // Bind to window with namespace
          EVENT_DBLCLICK = "dblclick",
          EVENT_BUILD = "build" + CROPPER_NAMESPACE,
          EVENT_BUILT = "built" + CROPPER_NAMESPACE,
          EVENT_DRAG_START = "dragstart" + CROPPER_NAMESPACE,
          EVENT_DRAG_MOVE = "dragmove" + CROPPER_NAMESPACE,
          EVENT_DRAG_END = "dragend" + CROPPER_NAMESPACE,

        build: function () {
          var $this = this.$element,
              defaults = this.defaults,
              buildEvent,
              $cropper;

          if (!this.ready) {
            return;
          }

          if (this.built) {
            this.unbuild();
          }

          $this.one(EVENT_BUILD, defaults.build); // Only trigger once
          buildEvent = $.Event(EVENT_BUILD);
          $this.trigger(buildEvent);

          if (buildEvent.isDefaultPrevented()) {
            return;
          }

          // Create cropper elements
          this.$cropper = ($cropper = $(Cropper.TEMPLATE));

          // Hide the original image
          $this.addClass(CLASS_HIDDEN);

          // Show and prepend the clone iamge to the cropper
          this.$clone.removeClass(CLASS_INVISIBLE).prependTo($cropper);

          // Save original image for rotation
          if (!this.rotated) {
            this.$original = this.$clone.clone();

            // Append the image to document to avoid "NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE" error on Firefox when call the "drawImage" method.
            this.$original.addClass(CLASS_INVISIBLE).prependTo(this.$cropper);

            this.originalImage = $.extend({}, this.image);
          }

          this.$container = $this.parent();
          this.$container.append($cropper);

          this.$canvas = $cropper.find(".cropper-canvas");
          this.$dragger = $cropper.find(".cropper-dragger");
          this.$viewer = $cropper.find(".cropper-viewer");

          defaults.autoCrop ? (this.cropped = TRUE) : this.$dragger.addClass(CLASS_HIDDEN);
          defaults.dragCrop && this.setDragMode("crop");
          defaults.modal && this.$canvas.addClass(CLASS_MODAL);
          !defaults.dashed && this.$dragger.find(".cropper-dashed").addClass(CLASS_HIDDEN);
          !defaults.movable && this.$dragger.find(".cropper-face").data(STRING_DIRECTIVE, "move");
          !defaults.resizable && this.$dragger.find(".cropper-line, .cropper-point").addClass(CLASS_HIDDEN);

          this.$scope = defaults.multiple ? this.$cropper : $document;

          this.addListeners();
          this.initPreview();

          this.built = TRUE;
          this.update();

          $this.one(EVENT_BUILT, defaults.built); // Only trigger once
          $this.trigger(EVENT_BUILT);
        },
```

Comment: So, this is the HTML, but where's the jQuery code you're actually asking about?

Comment: @jfriend00 So this uses v1.11.1  //code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js it's called from <script src"..."> </script> at the end of the html page. My first thought was it's a incompatibility with the type of loop I'm using, not the js itself, as everything does work in the first data item of the loop.

Comment: I'm not asking about jQuery itself.  I'm asking about the custom Javascript you wrote yourself.  Where is this loop you're referring to?  We need the code for that Javascript/jQuery loop that you are actually asking about.

Comment: @jfriend00 it was the php while loop i was referring to. The js is huge but I will append it.

Comment: @jfriend00 there are actually no loops in the js file

Comment: If you want to evaluate the results of the PHP loop, then use View/Source and look at the generated HTML in the browser (e.g. the results of the PHP).  If you want help understanding why clicking on something in the browser isn't triggering a JS event handler, then we will have to see both a representative sampel of the generated HTML and the JS code that hooks up event handlers.  In case this isn't clear to you, the PHP runs ONLY on the server.  It's job is to generate the page.  That page is then delivered to the browser and clicks are handled ONLY in the browser.

Comment: this is making sense. However, how do I view a "representative sample of the generated html", viewing the page source after I trigger the event doesn't include the modal. Is there a way to view that generated html after the click function is executed?

Comment: The modal isn't in the page source that comes from the server.  It is generated dynamically by some javascript on your page.  You could view it using the DOM inspector in any browser debugger, but I don't know why that matters to you at all.  Your issue is likely with the javascript code that hooks up click event handlers.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thannk you, I posted what I believe is the js event (BUILD) in question.

Comment: I don't see any click handlers getting installed in the JS code you included.

Comment: I think i need to study up a little more to be able to ask the right questions here. I'm very weak with js. thank you for all the information today @jfriend00

Comment: If the site is public, you could include a link to the live page and a description of which click isn't working and I might have a chance to look into it later.

Comment: @jfriend00 it's public now!!! ;-)  http://www.mblistings.com/members_area/edit_listings.php  my db is backed up so no worries if you change anything. Any suggestions here would be appreciated. if you click on first list item you will see it works fine, but click on any of the other items below it and you have no functionality. Also, I'm starting to wonder if this is a twitter bootsrap issue even, still reading up

Answer (score 1):

The root of your problem is two-fold (and there may be other issues behind this).

**First**, you have tons of duplicate id values in your HTML.

Here are some of the dups: `edit_listing`, `container`, `edit_left`, `crop-avatar`, `avatar-modal`, etc...

A given ID can only be used ***once*** in the entire HTML document.   All of these id values need to be changed to class names (which can be used as many times as you want) and then any code or CSS that references them needs to be changed to refer to the class name, not the ID value.

This comes into play in your code when you do:

```
new CropAvatar($("#crop-avatar"));
```

Because this is an id reference, it will only select the first element in your page with that id.  Thus, only the first listing is active.  If you change the HTML to be:

```
<div class="container crop-avatar">
```

then, you can select all of them with a class selector `.crop-avatar`.

**Second**, your `CropAvatar()` constructor is only ever called once, but it's written as if it is only going to be operating on a single avatar.  So, either you need to call `CropAvatar()` separately for each listing OR you need to rewrite `CropAvatar()` and it's event handlers to work for all the listings instead of just one.

You could probably make the existing `CropAvatar()` constructor work if you fix all the duplicate ID values and then change this:

```
var example = new CropAvatar($("#crop-avatar"));
```

to this:

```
 $(".crop-avatar").each(function() {
     new CropAvatar($(this));
 });
```

This will call the `CropAvatar()` constructor for each listing.

---

These are the first two main issues I see.   I cannot promise that there are not other things to fix also, but those issues can't be seen until these first two are fixed.